# Why image does not appear in vuejs project

Tags: webpack, vue.js, ecmascript-6

In my project, I use Vue.js+es6+webpack.

I have define img address in data.json

```
 "seller": {
 "avatar": "http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg",
  }
```

In App.vue

```
 <v-header :seller="seller"></v-header>
 .......
 <script type="text/ecmascript-6">
 import header from './components/header/header.vue'
 export default {
  data () {
    return {
    seller: {}
  }
},
created () {
this.$http.get('/api/seller').then(response => {
// get body data
  this.seller = response.body
  console.log(this.seller)//get seller content from data.json successfully
}, response => {
// error callback
})
},
components: {
 'v-header': header
 }
}
</script>
```

The header.vue content is :

```
 <div class="avatar">
      <img width="64" height="64" :src="seller.avatar">//works fail
 </div>
```

it is unlucky, the image does not appear.
When i chosed another way:

```
<div class="avatar">
      <img width="64" height="64" src="http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg">//works OK
 </div>
```

The full header.vue content is

```
<template>
<div class="header">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="avatar">
      <!--<img width="64" height="64" :src="seller.avatar">-->
      <img width="64" height="64" src="http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bulletin-wrapper"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
 export default {
   props: {
     seller: {
       type: Object
     }
   }
  }
</script>

<style lang="stylus" rel="stylesheet/stylus">
</style>
```

the content of console.log(this.seller)

```
data:{name: "JOHN）", description: "stack", deliveryTime: 38, score: 4.2, serviceScore: 4.1,…}
 avatar:"http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256
 px.jpg"
bulletin:"one"
deliveryPrice:4
deliveryTime:38
error:0
```

in webpack.dev.con.js

```
const appData = require('../data.json') 
const seller = appData.seller
... 
devServer: { 
before (app) {
app.get('/api/seller',(req,res) => {
res.json({
 errno: 0,
 data: seller
}) // return json
}),
```

It works OK. it seems nothing wrong, Who can help me?

Comment: It would help if you could show full header component code.

Comment: @Jared,see my update

Comment: try logging something in the `// error callback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json also seems broken, and it looks like the root property is `seller`, so the assignment should be:

```
this.seller = response.body.data;
```

Comment: @stack see my edit. it could be due to the structure of your json file. I was thinking that your json supposedly is `{"seller": {
 "avatar": "http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg",
  }}`

Comment: Yes, my json is {"seller": { "avatar": "http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg", }}

Comment: I have found all the object in console including avatar:"http://static.galileo.xiaojukeji.com/static/tms/seller_avatar_256px.jpg"

Comment: I have tested this.seller = response.body.seller; but got error in console:vue.esm.js?efeb:591 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined"

Comment: can you update your question to include the response of the `response.body`?

Comment: Paolo Dayay, thanks for your kindly hearted. Can you tell me why?